# can't shutdown weblogic from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, weblogic, shutdown

I have win7 x64 with eclipse 3.5 oepe and weblogic 10. 
 When I try to stop the server, eclipse seems to  not understand that the server was stopped. I can see the message on Console:

```
"C:/bea/jrockit_160_05/bin/java -classpath C:/bea/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar weblogic.Admin -url t3://localhost:80 -username admin -password admin FORCESHUTDOWN AdminServer
Server "AdminServer" was force shutdown successfully ..."
```

So, the server was stopped but eclipse did not understand this and the progress bar shows: "Shutting down server (%95)" and after 5 minutes it reaches timeout and can't stop.

After this the server start button became disabled.

The only solution is to close and restart the eclipse and kill all the java processes.

Any suggestion?

P.S.
Here are some additional logs

```
<22:29:22 IDT 21/08/2011> <Alert> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000396> <Server shutdown has been requested by admin> 
<22:29:22 IDT 21/08/2011> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SUSPENDING> 
<22:29:22 IDT 21/08/2011> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to ADMIN> 
<22:29:22 IDT 21/08/2011> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN> 
<22:29:22 IDT 21/08/2011> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel "DefaultSecure[5]" listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:443 was shutdown.> 
<22:29:22 IDT 21/08/2011> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel "DefaultSecure[3]" listening on fe80:0:0:0:8498:267d:c80c:802:443 was shutdown.> 
<22:29:22 IDT 21/08/2011> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel "Default[3]" listening on fe80:0:0:0:8498:267d:c80c:802:80 was shutdown.> 
<22:29:22 IDT 21/08/2011> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel "Default[1]" listening on fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:49:80 was shutdown.> 
<22:29:22 IDT 21/08/2011> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel "Default[5]" listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:80 was shutdown.> 
<22:29:22 IDT 21/08/2011> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel "DefaultSecure" listening on 192.168.0.73:443 was shutdown.> 
<22:29:22 IDT 21/08/2011> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel "Default" listening on 192.168.0.73:80 was shutdown.> 
<22:29:22 IDT 21/08/2011> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel "DefaultSecure[1]" listening on fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:49:443 was shutdown.> 
<22:29:22 IDT 21/08/2011> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel "DefaultSecure[2]" listening on fe80:0:0:0:810d:e511:28d2:27cc:443 was shutdown.> 
<22:29:22 IDT 21/08/2011> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel "Default[2]" listening on fe80:0:0:0:810d:e511:28d2:27cc:80 was shutdown.> 
<22:29:22 IDT 21/08/2011> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel "Default[4]" listening on 127.0.0.1:80 was shutdown.> 
<22:29:22 IDT 21/08/2011> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel "DefaultSecure[4]" listening on 127.0.0.1:443 was shutdown.>
```

Comment: One thing for sure is weblogic takes loads of time to start up and shutdown, also the connectors for weblogic or tomcat or jetty are not always fool proof in starting or stopping the servers. I guess you have to live with this. Or just try to create the server again.

Answer (score 1):

Killing **java.exe** process should force shutdown the Weblogic server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue. It started working when I moved the `eclipse` folder to root on `C:` drive. When eclipse was located in `C:\Program Files` or in `C:\Apps\ide` then it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem and solution was to start Eclipse with java command (in my case Weblogic was running as java.exe, but Eclipse as javaw.exe). Also check if the same version of JDK is used for running both Weblogic and Eclipse.